# Merging sorted arrays in Python

Tags: python

```py
def merge_arrays(list1, list2):
  len_list1 = len(list1); len_list2 = len(list2)
  merge_len = len_list1 + len_list2
  merge_list = []

  l1_ptr = 0
  l2_ptr = 0
  # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
  while(l1_ptr <= len_list1-1 and l2_ptr <= len_list2-1):

    if (list1[l1_ptr] <= list2[l2_ptr]):
      merge_list.append(list1[l1_ptr])
      l1_ptr += 1
    
    elif (list1[l1_ptr] > list2[l2_ptr]):
      merge_list.append(list2[l2_ptr])
      l2_ptr += 1
      
  if l1_ptr > len_list1-1: #list1 exhausted
    for item in list2[l2_ptr:]:
      merge_list.append(item)
  else:
    for item in list1[l1_ptr:]:
      merge_list.append(item)

  return merge_list
```

I am trying to merge sorted arrays in python. How can I improve this? Honestly it looks like I've written this in C and not in Python

Comment: There's a builtin function for this `from heapq import merge`... was this intentionally reinventing the wheel?

Comment: @Gerrit0 Or just `sorted(list1 + list2)`.

Comment: @superbrain that doesn't take into account that both lists have been sorted already

Comment: @MaartenFabré It does. I guess you're not familiar with Timsort?

Comment: The `elif:` seems not necessary, an `else:` is enough: once `list1[l1_ptr] <= list2[l2_ptr]` turned out false, `list1[l1_ptr] > list2[l2_ptr]` is true and doesn't need checking.

Comment: @MaartenFabré In particular, it also only takes linear time. And in some tests I just did, it was about 18 times faster than `list(merge(list1, list2))`.

Comment: I  seem to be learning something new every day

Comment: @superbrain as much as I agree that this is the simplest solution, and as much as I love Timsort, relying on an implementation detail is never ideal.

Comment: @njzk2 Hmm, I'd say it's more than just an ordinary implementation detail. [`sorted`'s documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) refers to [Sorting HOW TO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sortinghowto), which says *"The Timsort algorithm used in Python does multiple sorts efficiently because it can take advantage of any ordering already present in a dataset"*. So it's at least also in the documentaton, and without a *"CPython implementation detail"* warning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## various

- `merge_len` is unused
- the extra parentheses around the simple checks are unnecessary
- `l1_ptr <= len_list1-1` can be made more clearer as `l1_ptr < len_list1`
- using the variable name `l1_ptr` to save a few characters while making it harder to guess from the name what it does is not useful

Working with the indices directly is not really pythonic indeed. You can make this more generic, using `iter` and `next`, and work for all iterables.

## typing

add typing information:

```
import typing

T = typing.TypeVar("T")


def merge_sorted_iterables(
    iterable1: typing.Iterable[T], iterable2: typing.Iterable[T]
) -> typing.Iterable[T]:
```

This is extra explanation for the user of this function (and his IDE).

## docstring

Add some explanation on what the method does, expects from the caller, and returns.

```
def merge_sorted_iterables(
    iterable1: typing.Iterable[T], iterable2: typing.Iterable[T]
) -> typing.Iterable[T]:
    """Merge 2 sorted iterables.
    
    The items in the iterables need to be comparable (and support `<=`).
    ...
    """
```

## iterator

Instead of keeping track of the index you can use `iter` and `next`. You don't even need to add the items to a list, you can [`yield`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) them, so the caller of the method can decide in what way he wants to use this.

```
done = object()

iterator1 = iter(iterable1)
iterator2 = iter(iterable2)

item1 = next(iterator1, done)
item2 = next(iterator2, done)
while item1 is not done and item2 is not done:
    if item1 <= item2:
        yield item1
        item1 = next(iterator1, done)
    else:
        yield item2
        item2 = next(iterator2, done)
```

Then all that needs to be done is continue the iterator that is not finished

```
    if item1 is not done:
        yield item1
        yield from iterator1
    if item2 is not done:
        yield item2
        yield from iterator2
```

---

```
import typing

T = typing.TypeVar("T")


def merge_sorted_iterables(
    iterable1: typing.Iterable[T], iterable2: typing.Iterable[T]
) -> typing.Iterable[T]:
    """Merge 2 sorted iterables.
    
    The items in the iterables need to be comparable (and support `<=`).
    ...
    """
    done = object()
    
    iterator1 = iter(iterable1)
    iterator2 = iter(iterable2)
    
    item1 = next(iterator1, done)
    item2 = next(iterator2, done)
    
    while item1 is not done and item2 is not done:
        if item1 <= item2:
            yield item1
            item1 = next(iterator1, done)
        else:
            yield item2
            item2 = next(iterator2, done)

    if item1 is not done:
        yield item1
        yield from iterator1
    if item2 is not done:
        yield item2
        yield from iterator2
```

## testing

You can test the behaviour, starting with the simplest cases:

```
import pytest

def test_empty():
    expected = []
    result = list(merge_sorted_iterables([], []))
    assert result == expected

def test_single():
    expected = [0, 1, 2]
    result = list(merge_sorted_iterables([], range(3)))
    assert expected == result
    result = list(merge_sorted_iterables(range(3), [],))
    assert expected == result

def test_simple():
    expected = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    result = list(merge_sorted_iterables([0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]))
    assert result == expected
    result = list(merge_sorted_iterables([0, 2, 4], [1, 3, 5]))
    assert result == expected
    result = list(merge_sorted_iterables([3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2],))
    assert result == expected

def test_string():
    expected = list("abcdef")

    result = list(merge_sorted_iterables("abc", "def"))
    assert result == expected
    result = list(merge_sorted_iterables("ace", "bdf"))
    assert result == expected
    result = list(merge_sorted_iterables("def", "abc",))
    assert result == expected

def test_iterable():
    
    expected = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    result = list(merge_sorted_iterables(iter([0, 1, 2]), iter([3, 4, 5])))
    assert result == expected
    result = list(merge_sorted_iterables(iter([0, 2, 4]), iter([1, 3, 5])))
    assert result == expected
    result = list(merge_sorted_iterables(iter([3, 4, 5]), iter([0, 1, 2]),))
    assert result == expected

def test_comparable():
    with pytest.raises(TypeError, match="not supported between instances of"):
        list(merge_sorted_iterables([0, 1, 2], ["a", "b", "c"]))
```

## descending

Once you have these test in place, you can easily expand the behaviour to also take descending iterables:

```
import operator

def merge_sorted_iterables(
    iterable1: typing.Iterable[T],
    iterable2: typing.Iterable[T],
    *,
    ascending: bool = True,
) -> typing.Iterable[T]:
    """Merge 2 sorted iterables.
    
    The items in the iterables need to be comparable.
    ...
    """
    done = object()

    iterator1 = iter(iterable1)
    iterator2 = iter(iterable2)

    item1 = next(iterator1, done)
    item2 = next(iterator2, done)

    comparison = operator.le if ascending else operator.ge

    while item1 is not done and item2 is not done:
        if comparison(item1, item2):
            yield item1
            item1 = next(iterator1, done)
        else:
            yield item2
            item2 = next(iterator2, done)

    if item1 is not done:
        yield item1
        yield from iterator1
    if item2 is not done:
        yield item2
        yield from iterator2
```

I added the `ascending` keyword as a keyword-only argument to avoid confusion and keep backwards compatibility

One of its tests:

```
def test_descending():
    expected = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
    result = list(
        merge_sorted_iterables([2, 1, 0], [5, 4, 3], ascending=False)
    )
    assert result == expected
    result = list(
        merge_sorted_iterables([4, 2, 0], [5, 3, 1], ascending=False)
    )
    assert result == expected
    result = list(
        merge_sorted_iterables([5, 4, 3], [2, 1, 0], ascending=False)
    )
    assert result == expected
```

Comment: wow this is great, thank you so much. you have no idea how much more i have learnt from your explanation and just this small example. thank you for taking the time, truly!

Comment: Thanks for the tests, have been useful :-). Twice you wrote `expected == result` instead of `result == expected`, though. For consistency I think it would be better if all were the same.

Comment: I disagree 100% with the "typing" section.  The function is called "merge_sorted_iterables" and takes two arguments "iterable1" and "iterable2".  Of course they're iterables, and of course it returns an iterable.  You've added zero useful information, and broken the function signature over three lines, and completely counterfeit the beauty of Python's indentation.

Comment: In this case the typing information is a bit superfluous. But it helps the IDE, and in other, less trivial cases it can have a lot of value

Answer (score 7):

Use a [4-space indent](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation).

Don't repeatedly subtract 1 from the same unchanging value.

Simplify the compare conditional: just use `else`.

Take advantage of [list.extend()](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).

Drop the wrap-up conditionals: they aren't actually needed. Code like `zs.extend(xs[xi:])` will work fine even if `xi` exceeds the list
bounds.

Shorten the variable names to lighten the code weight and increase readability. There's no loss of meaning here, because all of the short names are quite conventional and make sense in a generic function like this.

```
def merge_arrays(xs, ys):
    # Setup.
    xmax = len(xs) - 1
    ymax = len(ys) - 1
    xi = 0
    yi = 0
    zs = []

    # Compare and merge.
    while xi <= xmax and yi <= ymax:
        if xs[xi] <= ys[yi]:
            zs.append(xs[xi])
            xi += 1
        else:
            zs.append(ys[yi])
            yi += 1

    # Merge any remainders and return.
    zs.extend(ys[yi:])
    zs.extend(xs[xi:])
    return zs
```

Last night I wrote an iterator-base solution but somehow forgot that `next()`
supports a handy `default` argument: the code was awkward and [Maarten
Fabré](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/248690/4612) did a nicer
implementation. But if your willing to use
[more_itertools.peekable()](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.peekable)
you can achieve a simple, readable implementation. Thanks to
[superb-rain](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/228314/superb-rain)
for an idea in the comments that helped me simplify further.

```
from more_itertools import peekable

def merge(xs, ys):
    xit = peekable(xs)
    yit = peekable(ys)
    while xit and yit:
        it = xit if xit.peek() <= yit.peek() else yit
        yield next(it)
    yield from (xit or yit)
```

Comment: How about [this](https://repl.it/repls/KaleidoscopicMammothPcboard#main.py)?

Comment: @superbrain Cool: good to know a peekable iterator can be checked for exhaustion in a simple `if`-test. I simplified my version even more.