# Mergesort in python

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

My mergesort implementation currently takes a very long time, for a list with 1 million elements it takes over 130 seconds to get the list sorted.

- Could someone kindly have a look at my code and suggest what could I do to improve it?
- Is there anything particular in my code that is taking significantly long?

#### Code

```
def splitlist(L): #splits the list to a list of individual listed elements (e.g. [1,2] to [[1],[2]])
    envelop = lambda x: [x]
    return(list(map(envelop,L)))


def merge(L_1,L_2): #merges two (already sorted) lists to one sorted list
    N = []
    while len(L_1) > 0 and len(L_2) > 0:
        if L_1[0] > L_2[0]:
            N += [L_2.pop(0)]
        else:
            N += [L_1.pop(0)]
    if len(L_1) == 0:
        N += L_2
    else:
        N += L_1
        
    return(N)


#performs one round of pairwise merges (e.g. [[2],[1],[4],[3]] to [[1,2],[3,4]]), or [[5,10],[1,8],[2,3]] to [[1,2,3,5,8,10]])   
def mergelist(L): 
    N = []
    if len(L) % 2 == 0:
        for i in range(0,len(L)//2):
            N += [merge(L[2*i],L[2*i + 1])]
    else:
        for i in range(0,len(L)//2 - 1):
            N += [merge(L[2*i],L[2*i + 1])]
        N += [merge(merge(L[-3],L[-2]),L[-1])]
    
    return(N)

def mergesort(L): #recursively performs mergelist until there is only 1 sorted list remaining
    L = splitlist(L)
    while len(L) > 1:
        L = mergelist(L)
    return(L[0])
```

Here is my code for generating the million elements:

```
rlist = random.sample(range(0,2000000),1000000)
```

Comment: You could use `numpy.array` instead of lists, those are better optimized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `pop(0)` takes linear time. Do that differently, in O(1) time. The standard way uses index variables. See [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/248679/228314)'s answers for some more pythonic ways. Or you could merge from right to left, using `pop()`, and then in the end `reverse()` the result.

One way to do the latter:

```
def merge(L1, L2):
    """Merges two (already sorted) lists to one sorted list."""
    N = []
    while L1 and L2:
        L = L1 if L1[-1] > L2[-1] else L2
        N.append(L.pop())
    N.reverse()
    N[:0] = L1 or L2
    return N
```

Other changes I did and which you can apply in the other parts of your code as well:

- Removed the underscores from the variables, I think it reads better. I kept them upper case because for `L`, that's what [PEP 8 says](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#names-to-avoid). And then I kept `N` for consistency. Usually I'd use `result` or maybe `merged`. Don't know why you chose `N`. If you have a meaningful word that starts with "n", then I suggest using that.
- Space between the function parameters.
- Proper docstring format instead of comment.
- Replaced `len(L_1) > 0` with the normal `L1` non-emptiness check.
- Replaced `N += [x]` with the normal `N.append(x)`.

Just another way, replacing that one "long" line to determine `L` with a clearer but slower way:

```
def merge(L1, L2):
    """Merges two (already sorted) lists to one sorted list."""
    N = []
    def last(L):
        return L[-1]
    while L1 and L2:
        L = max(L2, L1, key=last)
        N.append(L.pop())
    N.reverse()
    N[:0] = L1 or L2
    return N
```

For some fun, two list comprehension hacks:

```
def merge(L1, L2):
    """Merges two (already sorted) lists to one sorted list."""
    def end(L):
        return L[-1:]
    return [max(L2, L1, key=end).pop() for _ in L1 + L2][::-1]
```

```
def merge(L, R):
    """Merges two (already sorted) lists to one sorted list."""
    return [(R, L)[L[-1:] > R[-1:]].pop() for _ in L + R][::-1]
```

And I don't want to leave without a much faster way:

```
def merge(L1, L2):
    """Merges two (already sorted) lists to one sorted list."""
    return sorted(L1 + L2)
```

That's O(n) because of Timsort. And *fast* O(n) because of C code. If you think using the mighty `sorted` inside a mergesort defeats the purpose of writing the mergesort in the first place: Even that can be meaningful, if you're not just doing mergesort. At least once I wrote a mergesort with embedded counting of something, and I indeed used `sorted` just for the merging. Because that made my solution faster/shorter/simpler.

Even more efficient (both space and time):

```
def merge(L1, L2):
    """Merges two (already sorted) lists to one sorted list."""
    L1 += L2
    L1.sort()
    return L1
```

(If `L2` can be longer than `L1`, it might be advantageous to insert `L1` into `L2` instead.)

Comment: This is great thank you. Managed to get it to just over 10 seconds by merging from right to left

Comment: Um, could someone tell me why this deserves a downvote? How is this not useful?

Comment: (It was downvoted when it was only the first paragraph, before I added the rest. Still wondering how that first paragraph fits the "This answer is not useful" that the downvote button represents.)

Comment: For the list comprehension, what does the underscore in the last line mean?

Comment: @NishilPatel That's the conventional placeholder variable name for when you don't actually use the value. Here I don't. I just do `L1 + L2` to get the *number* of elements, so that the list comprehension has the correct length. At that place, I don't care what the elements are, so I assign them to `_`.

Comment: Ahh I see, thank you